# Change the style of an element if the fragment identifier (hash) in the URL references it

Tags: css

Is there a way, in pure CSS, to change the style of an element if the fragment identifier (hash) in the URL references it?

i.e.

Given this HTML:

```
<p id="reference">lorem ipsum</p>
```

And this URL:

```
http://example.com/#reference
```

The browser will scroll to the paragraph with the id of `reference`, but can I change the style of that element without JavaScript?

I thought I could do this with the `:focus` psuedo-class, but it did not work.  And the other 3 deal with mouse events (`:hover`, `:active`) and URLs (`:visited`), so none of these would work.

Comment: CSS is for styling. Behavior is controlled by Java Script

Comment: @LeoTheFour but I knew behavior Can be controlled by CSS3, with the modifiers, as I mentioned in the last sentence.  So I was wondering if there were others I did not know about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It’s easily done with CSS only, no JavaScript needed. Use the [**`:target`** pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp):

```css
p#reference:target{background-color:gold;}
```

```html
<p id="reference">lorem ipsum</p>
<a href="#reference">to target</a>
<a href="#">untarget</a>
```

Also [**read MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:target) for browser support (IE9+) and additional information.

Comment: Good job, I couldn't think of how to make a demo.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/ & https://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: I had a feeling this type of selector would exist, especially since CSS3 is capable of this type of thing.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a [`:target` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) that does exactly this, with reasonable support.

Comment: Good job ;) Greets