# How to apply CSS only on certain anchors

Tags: css, anchor

I've a website with 3 pages.

- https://mywebsite.com/#
- https://mywebsite.com/#features
- https://mywebsite.com/#download

I want to change the some of the CSS based on which anchor I'm at.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, what I get and what I expect.

```
#header-outer #social-in-menu a i::before{
    color: #000000;
}
```

This does change social button colors to black but on every anchor. I've tried to wrap it with `a[href*="features"]` so that it would only change in #features link but social icons remains white.

This is what I tried to achieve `show social icons black only in #features anchor`.

```
a[href*="features"] {
    #header-outer #social-in-menu a i::before{
        color: #000000;
    }
}
```

This one has no effect. Changes nothing. First part of CSS however does change icons to black but on all anchors.

How can I achieve this?

What I try to have as the end result is:

```
a[href*="features"] {
    #header-outer #social-in-menu a i::before{
        color: #000000; /* could be a different colour */
    }
}


a[href*="download"] {
    #header-outer #social-in-menu a i::before{
        color: #FFFFFF; /* could be a different colour */
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of CSS preprocessor, because nesting rules that that is invalid

Comment: I'm not familiar with CSS and I thought it'd work just like if statements in C++ or so. This is just CSS. Is there anyway to achieve this using only CSS? @j08691 edit: if not, what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Try `#header-outer #social-in-menu a[href*="features"] i::before` although I don't think that's the best solution.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio it sadly did nothing, here's the link of the actual website. It may give some ideas: https://dumanstudios.com/#features currently applied CSS: `#header-outer #social-in-menu a[href*="features"] i::before{color: #000000;!important}` social icons are on top left.

Comment: That's because the anchors have a blank `href` attribute? EDIT: Oh I think I understand what you need now. You want to use a different color for the social icons depending on the fragment identifier on the URI. Correct?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio yes! For example on green page, black icons, on red page white icons and such.

Comment: I think this might be different from what you need but this should give you an idea of what you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552994/5530965

Comment: So, I should try `a#features:target{color:black;}`, trying now. Wait, how do I include `#header-outer #social-in-menu i::before` with this?

Comment: What `:target` does is it selects the element with an `id` that is the same as the fragment identifier so you'll have to find a way to make sure that the social icons are wrapped in a parent element with the selected fragment identifier. Then do something like `div:target a i::before{color:black;}`.

Comment: Okay, I'll work from this thanks for the help @uom-pgregorio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
    $(".parent").attr("id", id);
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

#features a {
  color: red;
}

#download a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#features">Features</a>
  <a href="#download">Download</a>
</div>
```

What this does is basically update the `id` of the parent element that wraps your anchors. This solution doesn't use `:target` and involves the use of Javascript/Jquery.