# vue-router : router-link doesn't get active-class when scrolling inside page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to make **navbar** for a **landing** page .

I used `router-link` for item like this

```
<router-link :to="#features" target="_self">
   features
</router-link>
```

and when I click on the link it scroll the page and work perfectly

and every link that is **clicked** get `exact-active-class`

but if scroll **manually** it **doesn't** get this class .

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Simply add the correct CSS styles as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552994/5962802

Comment: i found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645225/vue-router-change-anchor-in-route-on-scroll